# Set custom compound component layout params programmatically?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm having a problem understanding how compound components work.
So I want to create a component that contains a few more components. It should be similar to if I include some layout via **`<include`** tag. The reason why I can't use include is: I want to add some logic to instace ComponentClass and **I need to add id programmatically**. Lets jump to code: I removed everything redundant and left basics for understanding. Here I placed component via `main_layout.xml` but I need to create it programmaticaly.

**main_layout.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <my.package.AjaxLoader/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**ajax_loader.xml** (my component):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height"wrap_content"
        android:text="Label" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**AjaxLoader.java**:

```
// Is LinearLayout root layout of component? What about inflated layout root component?
public class AjaxLoader extends LinearLayout {

    public AjaxLoader(Context context) { this(context, null, 0);    }

    public AjaxLoader(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { this(context, attrs, 0);}

    public AjaxLoader(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        View inflate = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.ajax_loader, this, true);
        /* Parent component is Relative layout( in main_layout.xml) so we use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams*/
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
             ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        setLayoutParams(layoutParams); // should I call this??
        inflate.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); // or this??? 
        // anyway both do not work :(
   }
}
```

I have a few questions:

- So if you noted I have `<my.package.AjaxLoader/>` in my main layout.
  Since  `AjaxLoader` extends `LinearLayout` it has to have
  `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes. I have a lot more
  attributes and I want to create them in constructor programmatically as I
  tried. But it doesn't work, android throws `You must supply a
  layout_width attribute`. In  example above I added element via xml and I could add there those params, but what happens when I create component via new and add it to another view?
- What structure does android creates? I have `AjaxLoader.java` extending `LinearLayout` and I inflate it with another `LinearLayout`. Does it mean it will generate `LinearLayout` -> `LinearLayout2` -> `TextView`? And if I implement `merge` as root of `ajax_loader.xml` it will generate `LinearLayout` -> `TextView`?' I need to have only `LinearLayout` -> `TextView`. Should I use `<merge` as in `ajax_loader.xml`and place all layour properties in my `AjaxLoader` class? Or I should use `LinearLayout` as root element `ajax_loader.xml` and move all layout properties there?
- I struggle to place this element to center of a screen. I have `RelativeLayout` as a parent element (in `main_layout.xml`). If I add
  `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to xml component (in `main_layout.xml`) it would go to center of the screen as I wanted. But remember, I want to create it programmaticaly. So I created `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams` add set it to `inflate` and `this` but it didn't work. I guess the same reason it didn't work with `layout_width` and `layout_height`. How do I set those properties to components' `LinearLayout`?
- Also is there any good article about android compound components? I read [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) and [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html) still I can't figure out what's going on.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated!

Best regards,

Comment: LayoutParams of the child must match the type of the parent. E.g., your `AjaxLoader` needs to have `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: yeah, I know this, I even noted it in the code.